# How to pass data from MVC Controller to Aurelia component?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aurelia

I am creating an Aurelia application using server side routing with MVC, and I am wondering if it possible to pass the Model from the View to the Aurelia component.

My Controller is something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = "test vm data"

    return View( vm );
}
```

With my View in Index.cshtml file something like this:

```
@model string

<div id="my-aurelia" aurelia-app="main" start="test-component"></div>
```

And main.js something like this:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

    aurelia.start().then(a => {
        let start = a.host.attributes.start.value;
        a.setRoot(start);
    });
}
```

The app works but I don't have access to `"test vm data"` in `test-component`. How can I pass the `@model` from the MVC Controller / Index.cshtml for use in `test-component.html` / `test-component.js`?

Comment: You aren't inserting the `@model` data in to the HTML anywhere. You'll need to do that. I recommend accomplishing this by utilizing the strategy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024102/aurelia-starting-with-params-passed-by-php/40024947#40024947

Comment: Alternatively if you switch to using `enhance` instead you can use something like `<test-component value.bind="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@model))></test-component>` which doesn't fit your request above but may offer more in terms of what you are looking for, if you aren't looking for routing.

Comment: How much I use the Aurelia router in conjunction with this? I am now able to pass the vm from the Controller to the component, but is there a way to use Aurelia's router for navigation, but still pull down data from the server when I move to a new view? Without refreshing the entire page